# How to move the edit tab in node.tpl.php

Tags: nodes, routes

The $tabs variable is being printed in page.tpl.php, but I want to move it under the title of my node. I can't use the $tabs variable in my node template and I don't see the variable being prepared in template.php as well.

How can I get $tabs to show where I want in my node template file?

Comment: The page (node) title should also be printed in page.tpl.php, can't you just move the tabs below that?

Comment: I am printing $title in my node template. I have a difficult html structure and can't print those in page.tpl.php which is why I am asking this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$tabs` variable is set up in [`template_preprocess_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7); you can add the same var to the node template file by implementing a preprocess hook:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['tabs'] = menu_local_tabs();
}
```